# How can I reference a record that has been created in bookshelf.js?

Tags: express, bookshelf.js

I am trying to update a record using bookshelf.js. When I update it, I want to reference the timestamp from when it was created. The code I have looks like this:

```
router.patch('/session/:id', (req,res) => {  
  const time = new Date() 
  console.log(time.getTime()) 
  Session
    .forge({id: req.params.id})
    .save({isTermed: true, duration: time.getTime() - Session.created_at})
    .then((session) => {
      res.json(session);
   })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

However, I think Session.created_at is undefined, and moreover, that this is not the proper way to reference the session I am looking for. So, what is the proper way? Also, if I were able to get this to work, I am trying to set the duration attribute to be the current time - the time created, in minutes. Since they are both just timestamps, how would I convert this value to minutes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch your model first, otherwise it won't have any of the data from your database:

```
router.patch('/session/:id', (req,res) => {  
  const time = new Date() 
  console.log(time.getTime()) 
  Session
    .forge({id: req.params.id})
    .fetch()
    .then((session) => {
      return session.save({
        isTermed: true,
        duration: time.getTime() - session.created_at
      })
    })
    .then((session) => {
      res.json(session);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```